# Bloquear rotação de um site na versão mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um site que gostaria de travar sua posição no *screen* quando acessado de um dispositivo móvel, impedindo que ele girasse ou rotacionasse junto com o celular.

Existe algum código em JavaScript que faça isso? Bloquear a rotação da tela como se fosse um aplicativo?

Comment: Parece que a [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.lockOrientation) que permitiria isso ainda é experimental e sem suporte. Ver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298467/prevent-orientation-change-in-ios-safari (em inglês) para uma possível alternativa. Ver também https://gist.github.com/visnup/2605440 (parece uma solução mais simples).

Comment: Infelizmente, com a tecnologia web que temos, isso ainda não é possível, porque não é controlado pelo site em questão, mas sim pelas configurações do aparelho e o site não tem o poder de interferir nisso como se fosse um aplicativo. Isso seria uma brecha de segurança, caso ocorresse.

Comment: Isso é possível sim. Entre em http://www.mcdonalds.com.br/favoritos e veja que você só pode usar na horizontal

Comment: Porque você não usa algo como calcular a resolução? Muitos smartphones utilizam 480 x 854 pixels. Você pode, por exemplo, se a resolução for menor que 500 px, exibir uma mensagem para rotacionar a tela.

Comment: Oi bfavaretto, obrigada pela ajuda. Estava testando os códigos que vc passou e eles não funcionam para a orientation landscape, que era o que eu realmente precisava... Tentei no mais simples: @media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
Mas nao funcionou...

Answer (score 2):

As cores são só para você ter uma ideia. Isso não pareceu muito bom, pelo menos no meu Moto X (Chrome, Android 4.4).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Teste de orientação no mobile</title>
        <style>
            #wrapper { width: 400px; height: 400px; }
            #wrapper.paisagem { -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); background-color: lightgreen; }
            #wrapper.retrato { background-color: lightblue; }
        </style>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(){     // funciona com addEventListener('resize', ...) também!
                if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) document.getElementById('wrapper').className = 'retrato';
                else document.getElementById('wrapper').className = 'paisagem';
            });

            window.addEventListener('load', function(){
                document.getElementById('wrapper').className = 'retrato';
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='wrapper'>
            <h2>Teste de orientação no mobile</h2>
            <p>
                Gire para ver.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```